# WSo2 tls connection to mongodb dataservice

Tags: mongodb, tls1.2, wso2-micro-integrator

I setup a data service to a mongodb server. It is working ok, but now I'm trying to increase my data flow security, since the mongodb is a GPC instance.

I can enable tls at mongo, but how do I enable TLS connection from wso2 to the mongodb server?

I haven't found any useful information.

Comment: What is wso2 and have you looked at its documentation?

Comment: WSO2 is a very interesting set of tools.. www.wso2.com, and OF COURSE I have read the documentation...

Comment: A link to their documentation explaining how they intend you to connect to MongoDB won't hurt.

Comment: Here is the documentation https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Exposing+MongoDB+as+a+Data+Service

Comment: That is ancient, the newest MongoDB they reference (2.4) is generally not supported by  currently shipping official  drivers.

Comment: That is why I'm here asking :)

Comment: The client needs to support TLS connections. I don't see anything in the documentation that says wso2 does. If they don't you can try something like stunnel but this would work only for standalone or sharded cluster deployments, not replica sets.

Comment: yeah, that's whay I was thinking.. I already have vpn's tunnels between several servers... so I think I will use vpn then..